# Flatten XML, change node then add to dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

Here is part of my very long XML (over 223 nodes)

```
<ApplicationExtraction>
<ApplicationDate>10/06/2015</ApplicationDate>
<Status>Application Received</Status>
<EquipmentType>Equipment</EquipmentType>
<GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties>
<Item>
<RelationshipType>Primary Lessee</RelationshipType>
<PartyNumber>20000107</PartyNumber>   
<FirstName>Parvesh</FirstName>
<LastName>Musharuf</LastName>
<DateOfBirth>12/12/1993</DateOfBirth>
<CreationDate>10/06/2015</CreationDate>
</Item>
<Item>
<RelationshipType>Co-Lessee</RelationshipType>
<PartyNumber>20000108</PartyNumber>
<IsCorporate>No</IsCorporate>
<FirstName>Pary</FirstName>
<LastName>Mushroom</LastName>
<DateOfBirth>1/12/1953</DateOfBirth>
<CreationDate>10/06/2015</CreationDate>   
</Item>
</GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties>
</ApplicationExtraction>
```

I created dictionary `Dictionary<string, string> xmlData = new Dictionary<string, string>();` and want to add node as key and node value as value.

I got part of it work until 2nd Item child nodes. It gives me the error of "An item with the same key has already been added". Now I want to add sequence number to the node Item so that I won't get this error. Ideally, I want something like this:

```
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item1.RelationshipType
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item1.PartyNumber
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item1.FirstName
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item2.RelationshipType   
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item2.PartyNumber
```

Is it possible to achieve this? 
I tried to catch the error and split the string to put number in but don't know how to increase the sequence probably instead I got:

```
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item1.RelationshipType
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item2.PartyNumber
ApplicationExtraction.GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties.Item3.FirstName
```

This is my code. result only contain path(node) and value

```
foreach (var p in result)   
    {   try
        {   key = p.Path;
            value =p.Value;
            xmlData.Add(key,value); }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {   i++;            
            if (exc.Message == "An item with the same key has already been added.")                             
            {
                pos = key.IndexOf("Item");
                if (pos !=-1 )
                {   
                    strTemp1 = key.Substring(0,key.IndexOf("Item")+4);
                    strTemp2 = key.Substring(pos + 4,key.Length - pos - 4);
                }   
                key = strTemp1 + "[" +  i.ToString() + "]" + strTemp2;
                value =p.Value;
                xmlData.Add(key,value);                     
            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to step through in debugger?

Assuming `i equals 0` at the top of the loop:

For the first iteration you will add `Item.RelationshipType`, `Item.PartyNumber`, etc.

For the second item, you get exception at `Item.RelationshipType` and you will instead use `Item[1].RelationshipType`.

For that second item itself, you will then get exception for `Item.PartyNumber` as well, `i` will be incremented to `2` and the key you will use will be `Item[2].PartyNumber`.

This is why you are seeing the keys that you see.

There are multiple ways to get the correct key. One is to keep track of current item number, which you can increment when you see the `<item>` tag, and use it for all sub-elements.

Comment: Yes, I did debug a few times. 

Yes, i  = 0 before the loop.

I think I don't have i++ at the right position or I have to do 2 loops to keep track of when there is child node.

Comment: I finally got it work the way I want. Thanks to @Miserable Variable suggestion, I figured a loop to keep track of parent  node so that I can increate the count correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a List of Tuple 
 which can collect all the values of the xml.
 add each item in the xml,to the list

```
List.Add(Tuple.Create((Relationship.value,PartyNumber.value...);
```

To fetch each one in the list, give `lst[i].item1,lst[i].item2` which will provide you the xml `Item[i].RelationshipValue,Item[i].PartyNumbervalue`

Comment: I am new to C#. I will have to read more about Tuple. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I would do it.  If you are getting an error that the key already exists it is due to your dictionary have duplicate keys.  I would use the PartyNumber as the key in the dictionary.  if you have more than one entry for a part number than the dictionary must be defined as Dictionary>.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication61
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<ApplicationExtraction>" +
                    "<ApplicationDate>10/06/2015</ApplicationDate>" +
                    "<Status>Application Received</Status>" +
                    "<EquipmentType>Equipment</EquipmentType>" +
                    "<GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties>" +
                        "<Item>" +
                            "<RelationshipType>Primary Lessee</RelationshipType>" +
                            "<PartyNumber>20000107</PartyNumber>" +
                            "<FirstName>Parvesh</FirstName>" +
                            "<LastName>Musharuf</LastName>" +
                            "<DateOfBirth>12/12/1993</DateOfBirth>" +
                            "<CreationDate>10/06/2015</CreationDate>" +
                        "</Item>" +
                        "<Item>" +
                            "<RelationshipType>Co-Lessee</RelationshipType>" +
                            "<PartyNumber>20000108</PartyNumber>" +
                            "<IsCorporate>No</IsCorporate>" +
                            "<FirstName>Pary</FirstName>" +
                            "<LastName>Mushroom</LastName>" +
                            "<DateOfBirth>1/12/1953</DateOfBirth>" +
                            "<CreationDate>10/06/2015</CreationDate>" +
                        "</Item>" +
                    "</GetActiveLeaseApplicationParties>" +
                "</ApplicationExtraction>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            Dictionary<int, Item> dict = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
            foreach (XElement item in doc.Descendants("Item").AsEnumerable())
            {
                Item newItem = new Item() {
                    relationshipType = item.Element("RelationshipType").Value,
                    partyNumber = int.Parse(item.Element("PartyNumber").Value),
                    isCorporate = item.Element("IsCorporate") == null ? false :
                       item.Element("IsCorporate").Value  == "Yes" ? true : false,
                    firstName = item.Element("FirstName").Value,
                    lastName = item.Element("LastName").Value,
                    dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("DateOfBirth").Value),
                    creationDate = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("CreationDate").Value)
                };
                dict.Add(newItem.partNumber, newItem);
            }

        }
        public class Item
        {
            public string relationshipType { get; set; }
            public int partyNumber { get; set; }
            public Boolean isCorporate { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public DateTime  dateOfBirth { get; set; }
            public DateTime creationDate { get; set; }

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank @jdweng but I need to get all the node in this XML not just the Items. It is a very long XML so I can just access each node like your suggestion. I need to a generic way to flatten the XML, get all the nodes and their value into a dictionary then send that dictionary to somewhere else. I have more than XML files to process so this solution is not practical but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: The best method is to create a class like I did.  If you need more items in the class the just add properties.  You can't generically just flatten an xml and expect it to work.  You must have a plan.  A dictionary is really a database and just throwing items into a database doesn't mean you can get them out.

Comment: In fact, I got it to work without creating class with all the names of the XML nodes.

Comment: The class would be more efficient than anonymous linq q and more understandable. The real test is the speed of looking up results.